# listen to local storage changes inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

I have a context variable to check if the user is authenticated or not, what i want to do is to update the context variable whenever the local storage has changed here's the **authContext.js** code

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const authContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [isAutenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUser = () => {
      const auth = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated") ? true : false;

      if (auth !== null) {
        setIsAuthenticated(auth);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("storage", checkUser);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", checkUser);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={[isAutenticated, setIsAuthenticated]}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAuthContext() {
  return useContext(authContext);
}
```

after calling the api, the local storage is changed but the context variable doesn't change

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) the event is only triggered by changes made by other pages under the same domain (see the blue box).

Comment: Maybe a wrapper around `localStorage` that triggers the `storage` event on `window` when `.setItem()` is called could solve this.

Comment: @Palladium02 so there is no way to make it in that way?

Comment: The solution proposed by Danny would work. This is a [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) you would like to check out for that matter.

Comment: axios interceptor

`const responseInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      
      localStorageWrapper.setItem('isAuthenticated', response?.data?.userIsConnected);
    }
  );
`
the wrapper 
`const localStorageWrapper = {
    setItem: (key, value) => {
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));
    },
    getItem: (key) => localStorage.getItem(key),
    removeItem: (key) => {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));
    },
  };
  export default ...;`

Comment: thank uou @Danny, that works for me

Comment: @HichemNeggaz, answer the post with the solution to mark it as solved.